# Physics and Ela exam question - Probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, education

I had to solve the following questions and I've provided all my work in order to get to the solutions. Could someone let me know whether I have done them properly?

---

Question(s):

> There are 59 students, out of which 50 are writing the ela exam,
> 22 are writing a physics exam and 20 are writing both. Round answers to the nearest thousandth.
>
> a) determine the probability, that a randomly selected student isn't
> writing the ela or physics exam.
>
> b) determine the probability, that a randomly selected student is
> writing either the ela or the physics exam.
>
> c) determine the probability, that a randomly selected student is
> writing only the physics exam.

---

established facts:

- 20 students are taking both exams (given)
- 30 (50 [ela students] - 20 [ela and physics students]) students are taking the ela exam
- 2 (22 [physics students] - 20 [ela and physics students]) students are taking the physics exam
- 7 (59 - [20 + 30 + 2]) students aren't taking either of the tests

---

visuals/different ways of viewing the problem?

let E represent the set of ela

let P represent the set of physics

let B represent the set of both ela and physics

E = {30}

P = {2}

B = {20}

or it can also be seen as:

[image]

---

My work:

**a)** take the # of students who aren't taking the exams (7) and divide it by the total # of students (59).

= 7/59 --> `0.119`

---

**b)** using the non-mutually exclusive probability formula:

P(A∪B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B)

where A is E (for ela) and B is P (for physics)

P(E∪P) = P(E) + P(P) - P(E∩P)

P(E∪P) =  50  +  22  -   20

P(E∪P) = 52

for the probability:

it's just taking P(E∪P) / 59 (total # of people)

= `0.881`

---

**c)** we know that there are only 2 students writing **just** the physics exam.

all we have to do here is take the # of students taking just the physics exam and dividing it by the
total # of students.

2/59 = `0.034`

Comment: At a glance, the results all look correct.  Good use of a venn diagram.  You have some awkwardness with how you wrote things however... You write for instance $P(E\cup P)=52$... you mean to say $|E\cup P|$ or $n(E\cup P)$ or whatever notation for the *quantity* of outcomes in the event... not the *probability* of such

Comment: Good understanding of [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Also, **regardless** of whether your work is accurate (which it is), very nice presentation, and good work shown.

Comment: thank you so much for the helpful comments! appreciate it :))